# Image Slider plugin repositioning images

Tags: css

Im having trouble with some images I have put in a wordpress slider plugin.

I am convinced it was fine last night though I didnt try it in other browsers, and it is still fine in FF and Opera but in Chrome and IE, my slider is in the right position as the pagination is correctly positioned but the actual sliding images are 140px lower than they should be.

Not too sure whats causing this, it is not a plugin problem as I have tried 2 different plugins and it is not a parent element problem as I have changed the divs around.

Anyone shed some light on this?

[my site](http://www.dragonsdesk.co.uk)

Comment: I could only really seem to stubbornly push this slider back up by adding `top: -135px;` to `.slideshow_content`! but it does seem like the slider wrapper is offset absolutely somewhere.

Comment: Only problem is that I think if I did that, it would then look OK in Chrome and IE but be 135px too high in FF and Opera.

Comment: I can only seem to replicate the issue you're speaking of in IE Compatibility mode, without it - it behaves as does the rest! :x

Comment: @MackieeE I have just found out it is because my headright div which contained search input and nav was positioned relatively with a top of -185, so the slider was nudged down to what would have been the bottom of the div although the content was 185px higher. In other words, I didnt hide the overflow, doing this has sorted it.